# logging "total-time" with varnishncsa (%D vs %T)

Tags: logging, varnish

I would like to have the "total-time" in seconds, but with a "microsecond" precision.

If I use %T I do not get precision.
If I use %D I get precision but the unity is not second.

Is any way to get "total-time" in seconds (float)?

Many Thanks

Iban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `%{VSL:Timestamp:Resp[2]}x`

Example command using the different variants:

```
varnishncsa -F "%T %D %{VSL:Timestamp:Resp[2]}x"
```

Example output:

```
0 535 0.000536
```